# VBA to copy and paste values for each sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code but it is only working on the active worksheet instead of looping through all of the work sheets.  I am not sure why it is not lopping as I have used the looping syntax below before.

```
Sub Paste_Values()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Dim WS As Worksheet



For Each WS In Worksheets
      Range("A1:V104").Select

    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify which sheet the range is on. Try `WS.Range("A1:V104").Copy`

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding Select *and* copy/paste:

```
Sub Paste_Values()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        With WS.Range("A1:V104")
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `WS.Range("A1:V104").Select` instead of `Range("A1:V104").Select`

Comment: This answer is correct. The _reason_ is that the unqualified `Range` in the OP works on the ActiveSheet, exactly as OP noted. That is the danger of using unqualified references and why they need to be avoided in _almost_ all cases.

Comment: I tried that and got a run time error.  I tried adding `WS.Select` after `For Each WS In Worksheets` section and did not put the `WS` in front of the `Range("A1:V104").Select` and it started to work.